# jqplot stacked bar, multiple series not getting stacked

Tags: jqplot

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart following example from the page http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/bar-charts.html, example 3. However, my series data are not getting stacked. Instead only the first series is plotted. My second and third series have values less than 1, whereas the first series had average values around 10, so I thought jqplot might be ignoring the other serieses as insignificant.

To confirm this is or is not the case, I copy pasted from the example there (sans mouse click fancy stuff), and still same result, with chart showing only one series.

```
    var s1 = [2, 6, 7, 10];
    var s2 = [7, 5, 3, 4];
    var s3 = [14, 9, 3, 8];
    var plot3 = $.jqplot('vmstats_0', [s1, s2, s3], {
        // Tell the plot to stack the bars.
        stackSeries: true,
        captureRightClick: true,
        seriesDefaults:{
          renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
          rendererOptions: {
              // Put a 30 pixel margin between bars.
              barMargin: 30,
              // Highlight bars when mouse button pressed.
              // Disables default highlighting on mouse over.
              highlightMouseDown: true   
          },
          pointLabels: {show: true}
        },
        axes: {
          xaxis: {
              renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
          },
          yaxis: {
            // Don't pad out the bottom of the data range.  By default,
            // axes scaled as if data extended 10% above and below the
            // actual range to prevent data points right on grid boundaries.
            // Don't want to do that here.
            padMin: 0
          }
        },
        legend: {
          show: true,
          location: 'e',
          placement: 'outside'
        }     
      });
```

Any suggestions where I need to tweak to make the series really stack?

Comment: As a sidenote: when I remove the "stackSeries: true," part, the three series do show up side-by-side. It is only when I try to stack them together that the 2nd and 3rd series vanish.

Comment: Seems it was an issue on my part, I did not copy the full jqplot plugins folder to my web server, only copying a minimal set of files that are referred in the scripts. Things worked fine after copying the full folder.